# Restful service argument mismatch exception

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest

I have a service

```
@POST
    @Path("/post")
    @Consumes("application/json")
    public Response createProductInJSON(Product product) {
        String result = "Product created : " + product;
        return Response.status(201).entity(result).build();
    }
```

and the consumer

```
url = new URL(
                "http://localhost:8080/TestRestWebService/json/product/post");
         conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Product p = new Product();
        p.setName("varun");
        p.setQty(33);
        String input = gson.toJson(p).toString();

        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        os.write(input.getBytes());
        os.flush();
        if (conn.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_CREATED) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                    + conn.getResponseCode());
        }
```

taken from [link](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/restfull-java-client-with-java-net-url/)

consumer is throwing

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed : HTTP error code : 500
at com.mkyong.rest.Consumer.main(Consumer.java:52)
```

where as the web service is throwing

```
SEVERE: Failed executing POST /json/product/post org.jboss.resteasy.spi.InternalServerErrorException: Bad arguments passed to public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.mkyong.rest.JSONService.createProductInJSON(com.mkyong.rest.Product)
(org.jboss.resteasy.spi.BadRequestException org.jboss.resteasy.spi.BadRequestException: Could not find message body reader for type: class com.mkyong.rest.Product of content type: application/json )
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:181)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch at
```

though`product` class has 2 params only `qty`, `name` only.

[image: Lib]

Comment: It says there's no reader (provider). Do you have a JSON provider? If not you should add it. See [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-jackson2-provider). Pick your RESTeasy version

Comment: didnt help, i had it added already

Comment: You added the jar or the dependency? A single jar is not enough.

Comment: @peeskillet - added screenshots of jars used

Comment: The Jackson provider is nothing without Jackson. You need the Jackson jars to go with it. See [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-jackson-provider/2.2.1.GA) scroll down and you will see four Jackson jars you need (click on the version). Also I have not used that old of a version of RESTeasy before. I don't know if it automatically register the provider, but try it out. If it doesn't work, then you probably will need to register the provider also

Comment: can you be specific please... havent worked much upon jackson not sure about its terminologies

Comment: Click the link I provided. Scroll down. You will see a list of four Jackson jars. Click the version button and it will take you to a page you can download the jar by clicking the download button. Download all four and add them. If it still doesn't work, let me know. You may also need to explicitly register the provider.

Comment: @peeskillet - please post this as answer, would be helpful for others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is

> Could not find message body reader for type: class com.mkyong.rest.Product of content type: application/json

This means that either you do not have a `MessageBodyReader` that can handle JSON or you have one and it is not registered.

In your case, you have the `resteasy-jackson-provider`, but it is still dependent on the rest of the core Jackson libraries, which are

- `jackson-core-asl`
- `jackson-jaxrs`
- `jackson-mapper-asl`
- `jackson-xc`

For your particular version of `resteasy-jackson-provider:2.2.1`, the Jackson version used is 1.6.3. You can download those jars [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-jackson-provider/2.2.1.GA). Just scroll down and click the <kbd>1.6.3</kbd> button for each of the jars and then click the <kbd>Download (JAR)</kbd> for each of those jars, and add them to your project.

For anyone else, that is not using the 2.2.1 version of RESTeasy, you should select the correct Jackson version that goes with your RESTeasy version. You can see [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-jackson-provider) and select the version of RESTeasy you are using.

Also note that the links I provided are for Jackson 1.x version, as that's the version that `resteasy-jackson-provider` uses. If you are using a newer 3.x version of RESTeasy, there is also Jackson 2.x support in the [`resteasy-jackson2-provider](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-jackson2-provider)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like 'application/json' could not be resolved

```
 @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
```

Make sure you have add the right dependency

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
   <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.13.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I have resteasy-jackson-provider jar available... still the same.. also media type didnt help

Comment: Do you want to return a JSON object? if this is the case, you must add @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

Comment: issue is its not able to map the method signature(not based on return type) but on basis of orgument