# Unable to load custom MessageBodyReader

Tags: java, rest, jboss

I have a REST endpoint interface with something as follows:

```
@POST
@Path("/")
@Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
MyResponse performAction(MyRequest request);
```

MyRequest class should be created using a custom MessageBodyReader, which I am attempting to do as follows:

```
@Provider
@Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public class MyRequestBodyReader implements MessageBodyReader<MyRequest > {

    @Override
    public boolean isReadable(final Class<?> type, final Type genericType, final Annotation[] annotations,
        final MediaType mediaType) {
        System.out.println("### we are gonna in the equality");
        return type == MyRequest.class;
    }

    @Override
    public MyRequest readFrom(final Class<MyRequest> type, final Type genericType,
        final Annotation[] annotations, final MediaType mediaType,
        final MultivaluedMap<String, String> httpHeaders, final InputStream entityStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        System.out.println("unmarshalling");
        return JAXB.unmarshal(entityStream, MyRequest.class);
    }

}
```

However, when I deploy my applicaiton to Jboss, I get an error stating:

```
Could not find message body reader for type: com.some.MyRequest of content type: text/plain
```

To try and see if dependencies are an issue, just for sake, I have added almost all resteasy references to my pom as a provided such as this:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-jaxrs-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.switchyard.components</groupId>
        <artifactId>switchyard-component-resteasy</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-cdi</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.6.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.6.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.6.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.6.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jsapi</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.6.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

All of those dependencies are within my jboss eap module folder. Am I missing something in the dependency section or in the configuration inorder for my MessageBodyReader to be taken?

Looking at the docs [here](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.3.6.Final/userguide/html/Content_Marshalling_Providers.html), it is stated that:

> The Resteasy ServletContextLoader will automatically scan your WEB-INF/lib and classes directories for classes annotated with @Provider or you can manually configure them in web.xml. See Installation/Configuration

I have examined the war file that is generated, and I was able to confirm that the WEB-INF directory contains a lib folder, and my jars (out of which one of them contains the provider) is actually present. However, it seems that the automatic scanning is not picking it up.

I tried the solution by [mkyong](https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/resteasy-could-not-find-messagebodywriter-for-response-object-of-typexx-of-media-type-applicationxml/), but this did not solve the issue for me.

I have used the approach from the [documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/message-body-workers.html#d0e7240) towards even attempting to correctly invoke the message body writer.

I have tried making a web.xml file, with the following contents, with no success.

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.resources</param-name>
        <param-value>com.some.MyRequestBodyReader</param-value>
    </context-param>
</web-app>
```

I have also tried parsing stackoverflow, but it seems that most issues related to the writer are with missing libraries where there is no custom writer, alike this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33493190/restful-service-argument-mismatch-exception)

Comment: Don't you need to say: `@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })` in `MyRequestBodyReader` instead of `@Consumes`?

Comment: @ɐuıɥɔɐɯ I think that MessageBodyWriter would be the one to do that, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like switchyard and jboss eap version combination I am using [does **NOT** support the @Provider annotation at the time being](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/242192). I'll update the answer if I manage to come up with a custom solution.